# How could i remove specific value from jquery array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to remove specific value from an array , I have tried following script for delete value from an array but that not working.

**HTML that contain values of an array**

```
<input type="hidden" class="image_array" id="image_array" name="image_array[]" value="20200207050212.jpg,20200207050214.jpg">
```

So my array value is `20200207050212.jpg,20200207050214.jpg` & I would like to remove `20200207050212.jpg` from this array but not remove when i used following script.

**1** Way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", '.profile_delete_image', function(){
        var getImageName = $(this).attr('data-imagename');
        console.log(getImageName)
        var getImageArray =$('.image_array').val();
        var checkValueExist = (getImageArray.indexOf(getImageName) > -1);
        if(checkValueExist == true){
          var itemtoRemove = getImageName;
          getImageArray = $.grep(getImageArray, function(value) {
            return value != itemtoRemove;      
              console.log(getImageArray)
          });
        }
    });
})
```

**2** Way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", '.profile_delete_image', function(){
        var getImageName = $(this).attr('data-imagename');
        console.log(getImageName)
        var getImageArray =$('.image_array').val();
        var checkValueExist = (getImageArray.indexOf(getImageName) > -1);
        if(checkValueExist == true){
          var itemtoRemove = getImageName;
          getImageArray.splice(1,1);
        }
    });
})
```

NOte: when i do console.log it's return separated value like

```
2
0
2
0
0
2
0
7
0
5
0
2
1
2
j
p
g
```

So I don't want this i only want to remove given value from array and return an array with removed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `split()` to make string as array.

```js
var getImageName = '20200207050212.jpg' // Get your delete image name. 
var getImageArray = [];
getImageArray = $('.image_array').val().split(',');
getImageArray = getImageArray.filter(e => e !== getImageName);

console.log(getImageArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="image_array" id="image_array" name="image_array[]" value="20200207050212.jpg,20200207050214.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the snippet,
This is a simple example, here we have an array of `images`, when the button is clicked, it will get the images to delete from `image_array`.

Checks for if images_array has value, and convert it to array using `.split()`. Then iterate through the array and delete if the value in images array matched.

```js
var $ = jQuery;
var images = ['20200207050212.jpg', '20200207050214.jpg', 'abc.jpg', 'image_123123.jpg'];
$('#delete_image').on('click', function() {
  console.log('before delete', images);
  var image_arr = $('#image_array').val();
  image_arr = image_arr ? image_arr.split(',') : image_arr;
  if (image_arr.length) {
    image_arr.forEach(function(img) {
      if (images.indexOf(img) !== -1) images.splice(images.indexOf(img), 1)

    })
    console.log('after delete', images);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="image_array" id="image_array" name="image_array[]" value="20200207050212.jpg,20200207050214.jpg">

<button id="delete_image">Delete Image </button>
```

Comment: I always get following
Array after removing the element = ',2,0,2,0,0,2,0,7,0,5,3,5,4,2,.,j,p,g,',,,',2,0,2,0,0,2,0,7,0,5,3,5,4,4,.,j,p,g,'

Comment: @David did you run my snippet ??

Comment: Yes , but when i tried  i got same thing that i have just mentioned in comment

Comment: By the way where you pass deleted image name in your code? \

Comment: @David did you meant to remove `20200207050212.jpg` from this input ?? `<input type="hidden" class="image_array" id="image_array" name="image_array[]" value="20200207050212.jpg,20200207050214.jpg">`